# Reading data from SQL Server using Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to read data from Microsoft Sql Server (and oracle, mysql, etc.) into an rdd in a Spark application? Or do we need to create an in memory set and parallize that into an RDD?

Comment: this is gonna be unanswered for sure :P

Comment: seems so...any reason why? if it can munge data from everything, why not the most common stores?

Comment: you will have to wait for a few days to get this answered as the tag `apache-spark` is very solemnly used. Wait for a couple of days for the apache guys to answer your question.

Comment: You can certainly read the data into the driver and then parallelize that into an RDD. If you're looking for a more scalable solution, you probably want to look into using [`DBInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBInputFormat.html) with Spark's "Hadoop API" methods. I haven't done this before, but it seems like something good to look into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution to this from the mailing list. JdbcRDD can be used to accomplish this. I needed to get the MS Sql Server JDBC driver jar and add it to the lib for my project. I wanted to use integrated security, and so needed to put sqljdbc_auth.dll (available in the same download) in a location that java.library.path can see. Then, the code looks like this:

```
     val rdd = new JdbcRDD[Email](sc,
          () => {DriverManager.getConnection(
 "jdbc:sqlserver://omnimirror;databaseName=moneycorp;integratedSecurity=true;")},
          "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME Where ? < X and X < ?",
            1, 100000, 1000,
          (r:ResultSet) => { SomeClass(r.getString("Col1"), 
            r.getString("Col2"), r.getString("Col3")) } )
```

This gives an Rdd of SomeClass.The second, third and fourth parameters are required and are for lower and upper bounds, and number of partitions. In other words, that source data needs to be partitionable by longs for this to work.

Answer (score 6):

In Spark 1.4.0+ you can now use `sqlContext.read.jdbc`

That will give you a DataFrame instead of an RDD of Row objects.

The equivalent to the solution you posted above would be

`sqlContext.read.jdbc("jdbc:sqlserver://omnimirror;databaseName=moneycorp;integratedSecurity=true;", "TABLE_NAME", "id", 1, 100000, 1000, new java.util.Properties)`

It should pick up the schema of the table, but if you'd like to force it, you can use the schema method after read `sqlContext.read.schema(...insert schema here...).jdbc(...rest of the things...)`

Note that you won't get an RDD of SomeClass here (which is nicer in my view).  Instead you'll get a DataFrame of the relevant fields.

More information can be found here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases