# Apache Spark comparing files with SQL data

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, apache-spark

I going to use `Apache Spark` for processing big text files where in processing cycle is a part with comparing text-parts with data from big SQL table.

The task is:

```
1) Process files and break text into pieces
2) Compare pieces with database ones
```

Definitely, the bottleneck will be a SQL. I'm completely new to `Apache Spark` and while I'm sure, that `Subtask #1` is "his guy", I'm not fully sure, that the `Subtask #2` can be handled by Spark (I mean, in efficient way).

The question is how `Spark` deals with iterable selects from big SQL (maybe, cache as much as can?) in parallel and distributed environment?

Comment: Would it be possible/worthwhile for you to sqoop data from the tables into HDFS? Then your processing can entirely work on HDFS data.

Comment: @DPM Yeah, maybe, good note. What's about Spark SQL and its method `cacheTable()`?

Comment: Spark SQL is for letting you query a RDD using SQL syntax. It seems more like you need [JdbcRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD) if you want to read SQL data into Spark, as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239001/reading-data-from-sql-server-using-spark-sql)

Comment: @DPM Wish you to make your comment as an answer and I'll approve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer per request:

If you need to repetitively process data from a SQL data source, I usually find it worth using [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) to pull the data into HDFS so that my processing can run more easily. This is particularly useful while I'm developing my data flow, since I'll often run the same job on a sample of data several times in a short time period, and if it has been sqooped I don't have to hit the database server every time.

If your job is periodic/batch style (a daily data cleanup or report or something), this may be a sufficient implementation, and having a collection of historic data in HDFS ends up being useful for other purposes many times.

If you need live, up-to-the-minute data, then you'll want to use [JdbcRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD), as described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239001/reading-data-from-sql-server-using-spark-sql), which lets you treat a SQL data source as an RDD in your Spark data flow.

Good luck.